# What Kafka UIs and monitoring tools do you recommend?

Tags: software-development, gui, monitoring

I have been using Apache Kafka for quite a while and I am wondering, what tools to monitor your Apache Kafka data do you use?

As there are certain Kafka UIs and topic browsers available: which do you recommend for professional use?

The important key points:

- Desktop or web-based?
- Free or commercial?
- Ease of use?
- Enterprise support available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Xeotek KaDeck - Data hub for Apache Kafka]

**[Xeotek KaDeck](https://www.xeotek.com/kadeck/kafka-ui-and-kafka-topic-browser-for-professionals) is a free Apache Kafka monitoring solution** that runs as a cross-platform desktop application or as a web service ("Enterprise edition" only) on your desktop PC or container.

- Free (but also commercial version)
- Desktop & web version
- Very intuitive design (in my opinion)
- Enterprise support available

KaDeck focuses on data analysis, end-to-end monitoring and rapid prototyping of applications in Java and JavaScript. Complex queries (e.g. in JavaScript) can be written and relevant data can be filtered and displayed in a clear table. The temporal distribution of data sets and the data origin (as flow chart) is also displayed. Data can of course also be generated, topics can be managed and much more.

One of the most important unique selling points is that the application was designed in such a way that it can be used by developers, business departments and application operations alike.

The web version also offers role-based access management, audit logs and much more.

Furthermore, **KaDeck is not an infrastructure monitoring tool**. So if you primarily want to monitor the memory consumption of your brokers (etc.), you should instead take a look at one of the countless APM tools. This also makes sense because they can do a lot more than that, and infrastructure operations don't have to introduce a separate tool for each component.
KaDeck instead addresses the development and operation of applications, the analysis of data and processes for new business use cases and thus creates data transparency.

**I am the founder of Xeotek, so I am happy about your feedback.**